# JavaScript date/birthday input fields jump

Tags: jquery, input, tabs

I have 3 inline input text fields to enter a date

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="day" />
  <input type="text" name="month" />
  <input type="text" name="year" />
</form>
```

The interesting fields are day and month. They may contain up to 2 numbers. After typing the day, e.g. "05", i want the cursor to jump to the month field, in order to type the whole date in all 3 inputs without pressing tab or clicking into the next field.
One restriction is that if the user already entered a date some time ago the form fields are filled with that date, so the day field may already contain "05". If i click it now, the cursor should not already jump so that i can enter a new day.
There must already exists some (jquery) code snippet to do this?

Comment: did u google for similar plugins? what have you done so far?

Answer (score 7):

Try this little bit of JS:

```
function moveToNext(field,nextFieldID){
  if(field.value.length >= field.maxLength){
    document.getElementById(nextFieldID).focus();
  }
}
```

and then add this to your fields:

```
<input type="text" id="dd" maxlength=2 onkeyup="moveToNext(this,'mm')"/>
<input type="text" id="mm" maxlength=2 onkeyup="moveToNext(this,'yyyy')"/>
<input type="text" id="yyyy" maxlength=4 />
```

[Example](http://www.globalguideline.com/JavaScript_Guide/JavaScript_Examples.php?JScript=Jump_to_next_textbox_using_Form)

Comment: Well, my function now looks like this: function moveToNextField(field, length){
  $this = $(field);
  if(length >= field.maxLength){
    $this.parent().parent().next().find('input').focus().select();
  }
} However, if i type e.g. the day very fast, it will not jump to month, but first to month and then to year.

Comment: ah and of course on the fields: "onkeyup="moveToNextField(this, this.value.length)"" .... however if i type too fast, both events will have length 2

Answer (score 1):

I use this nice plugin and it does exaxtly what Merion asked for:

[Autotab](http://www.mathachew.com/sandbox/jquery-autotab/): jQuery auto-tabbing and filter.